# Identify a DOM element between requests if DOM element doesn't have an id attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, dom, local-storage

I wrote a quick and dirty solution to store (and activate) the last selected Bootstrap 3 nav tabs pane on page requests, using `localStorage` (actually with the help of [store.js](https://github.com/marcuswestin/store.js/) shim). It seems to work fine and yes, I'm not so good at JavaScript.

Anyways the script works storing the key computed based on the `window.location.href` and nav tabs `id` attribute:

```
<!-- Nav tabs -->
<ul id="nav-tab-settings" class="nav nav-tabs nav-remember">
    <li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#messages" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
    <li><a href="#settings" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="home"><h2>Home</h2></div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="profile"><h2>Profile</h2></div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="messages"><h2>Messages</h2></div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="settings"><h2>Settings</h2></div>
</div>
```

**Question**: `id` attribute for nav tabs is not mandatory in Bootstrap 3. Can I make my script work without forcing to set an `id` attribute? Is there a way to identify an DOM element without the `id` (maybe its position)? What if the same page returns a slightly modified DOM between requests?

If matters, here is the script `navs-remember.js`:

```
(function ($, store) {
    // Storage not available
    if (!store.enabled) {
        return;
    }

    $(function () {               
        var tabsSelector = '.nav.nav-tabs.nav-remember[id]',
            toggleSelector = 'a[data-toggle="tab"][href]';

        // Identify each nav tabs by current location and its id 
        var computeStorageKey = function (navId) {
            return window.location.href + '#' + navId;
        };

        // Restore last selected tab
        $(tabsSelector).each(function () {
            var nav = $(this),
                navId = nav.attr('id'),
                storedActiveHref = store.get(computeStorageKey(navId)),
                lastActiveToggle = null;

            if (!navId.length || (undefined === storedActiveHref)) {
                return;
            }

            // Get the toggle itself
            lastActiveToggle = nav.find('a[href="' + storedActiveHref + '"]')
                .first();

            // Show the tab
            if (lastActiveToggle.length) {
                lastActiveToggle.tab('show');
            }
        });

        $(tabsSelector + ' ' + toggleSelector).click(function () {
            var toggle = $(this),
                toggleHref = toggle.attr('href'),
                nav = toggle.closest(tabsSelector),
                navId = nav.attr('id');

            // Store toggle href attribute value
            if (toggleHref.length && nav.length && navId.length) {
                store.set(computeStorageKey(navId), toggleHref);
            }
        });
    });
}(jQuery, store));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can place it by position in the jquery results using `jQuery.eq(index)`, so to get the "home" tab, you would look for `$("tabselector li").eq(0)`

Note that it is 0 based.

---

Documentation: https://api.jquery.com/eq/

Comment: The problem is to uniquely store the nav tabs preferences in the localStorage. Because you can have different nav tabs with the same id in different pages. Is there any way to do this without using the id attribute?

Comment: @gremo If they're in different pages, because you're computing it with the ID and the URL of the page, surely it's a non-issue that they have the same ID on different pages. If you're only against an ID for the element, you could give it an attribute like `data-tab-id="GUID"`, otherwise you could get its parents (and `.eq` from that if it's likely to share a parent). If you upload a JSFiddle it might make it easier to see exactly what your problem it.